How failure(job) callback work in DelayedJob?
How does failure(job) callback work in DelayedJob?
I want that in my delayed job max_attempts is 5 and after 5 attempts, the job is failed then call failure(job) callback—in rails 6 or greater.
class MyJob < Struct.new(:some_param)
  def perform
     # Your job logic here   
  end
    
  def max_attempts
    3 # Set the maximum number of retry attempts
  end
    
  def failure(job)
    # Define what to do after the maximum failures
    handle_failure(job)   
  end
    
      private
    
      def handle_failure(job)
        # Your failure handling logic here
        # For example, send an email notification
        UserMailer.job_failed_notification(some_param).deliver_now   
      end 
end


Is this code not working?

No, it's not working I don't know why :(
